# Vue 3: Bind id attribute with variable, with partial custom text

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

We can bind attributes with :

Like `:id="single.id"`

what I want is PHP equivalent of this

```
id="FixText<?php echo $single->id; ?>"
```

so in vue, how can I add text FixText before single.id ?

Comment: ` `FixText${single.id}` ` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:id` is equal to `v-bind:id` So when you are binding some values you can put any valid JS code there.

Put your string into template strings and It will work:

`FixText${single.id}`